# Bootstrap switch checked event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I use this code for checkbox checked event but it does not work.

css

```
<link href="assets/plugins/bootstrap-switch/static/stylesheets/bootstrap-switch-metro.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

html

```
<div class="switch switch-mini" data-on-label="<i class='icon-sun icon-white'></i>" data-off-label="<i class='icon-sun muted'></i>">
    <input id="swWeather" type="checkbox" class="toggle" onclick="toggleWeather()" />
</div>
```

js

```
<script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap-switch/static/js/bootstrap-switch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If I use this way, just visual style work well but it does not trigger `toggleWeather()` function, but if I remove `bootstrap-switch.js`, all visual styles are removed and looks standard as standard checkbox, although it works very well.

How can I change checkbox checked status click it with bootstrap-switch?

Here my toggleweather code:

```
function toggleWeather() {

            if (document.getElementById('swWeather').checked)

            { weatherLayer.setMap(map); }

            else

            { weatherLayer.setMap(null); }

            if (document.getElementById('swCloud').checked)

            { cloudLayer.setMap(map); }

            else

            { cloudLayer.setMap(null); }
        }
```

by the way I use these switches with this theme:
http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic_admin/form_component.html#myModal

It is not good example but like that
http://jsfiddle.net/UHkN6/

Comment: Post the `toggleWeather` code here, or make a fiddle of the problem in  http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: try $(document).on('click','#swWeather',function(){}); for the click event

Comment: in which click event?
Where I must put on it?

Comment: Seems to be proper , just binned it here : http://jsbin.com/IYuMuLI/1/edit

Comment: It works like this, but it looks standard checkbox, if it looks bootstraps switch, it does not work properly

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UHkN6/

Answer (score 104):

**Note: The [bootstrap docs](http://bootstrapswitch.site/events.html) now use the second example.**

For bootstrap-switch 3.0 release candidate the event previously given as an example on the official page was:

```
$('#switch-change').on('switchChange', function (e, data) {});
```

It doesn't get fired!

Solution - use this instead :

```
$('#switch-change').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) {});
```

where `state` parameter is the value of the `checkbox`.

Comment: Just a note, but as of now, this still isn't fixed in the component or the documentation.

Comment: Not fixed today either

Comment: This should really be in the documentation. :D

Comment: How to reverse the state inside function (event, state) {}??

Comment: This did not work for me, but the one below did. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39450925/4526479

Answer (score 34):

For me this was the only working code (Bootstrap 3.0) :

```
$('#my_checkbox').on('change.bootstrapSwitch', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.checked);
});
```

It returns me ***true*** or ***false***

Example with Ajax submission on bootstrap switch change :

```
$('#my_checkbox').on('change.bootstrapSwitch', function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/uri/of/your/page',
        data: {
            'my_checkbox_value': e.target.checked
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Works for me, but `state` is `undefined`. You get the value from `e.target.checked` which seems to be the proper way to get at it.

Comment: Yes, aou're right, state is maybe not in use in this case. I'll remove it.

Comment: It works fine for `Bootstrap 4.3` `https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/` for the code `<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">Do it!</label>
                    </div>`

Answer (score 11):

This work for me.

```
$(".switch").bootstrapSwitch({
        'size': 'mini',
        'onSwitchChange': function(event, state){
            console.log('switched...')
        },
        'AnotherName':'AnotherValue'
    });
```

Answer (score 9):

The documentation provides the events for the bootstrap-switch. But [here](http://jsfiddle.net/skindeep/sumw4/) is an example that uses a single checkbox as well as a radio group just for completeness. I have also thrown in the Disable method as well.

```
$('#TheCheckBox').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function () {
   $("#CheckBoxValue").text($('#TheCheckBox').bootstrapSwitch('state'));
});
```

Answer (score 8):

You should call the switch-change function like below

```
$('.switch').on('switch-change', function () {
    console.log("inside switchchange");
    toggleWeather();
});
```

If you are seeing to create it dynamically, follow the steps given in the link which was previously posted by me. [ [create a radio bootstrap-switch dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291929/create-a-radio-bootstrap-switch-dynamically) ]

This is for radio type. For checkbox type you can change the `type='checkbox'`.

You can refer to the below link for more examples - http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/

Answer (score 2):

Try this worked for me

```
 $('#check').change(function (event) {
    var state = $(this).bootstrapSwitch('state');
    if (state) {
       // true
    } else {
       // false
    }
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the way that I use it:

**HTMl**:

```
<input name="field_name" class="switcher" type="checkbox" data-size="small" value="1">
```

**JQuery**:

```
$('.switcher').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
    if (state)
    {
        // Checked
    }else
    {
        // Is not checked
    }
});
```

I hope it is helpful!!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox" checked>

    $('input[name="my-checkbox"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) 
        {
              if (state == true) 
               {
                 //your code
               }
               else
               {
                  //your code
               }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

After trying everything I was able to acheive it using a click event.

```
  $('#threshold_status').on('click', function (event, state) {
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
           //code if checked
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for while using bootstrapSwitch

```
    $('body').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch','.switch',function () {
        alert('Done')
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just a stylized checkbox. So you can work with it in the same way as with checkboxes

```
document.addEventListener('change', function() {
    var chk = event.target
    if (chk.tagName === 'INPUT' && chk.type === 'checkbox') {
        console.log(chk.checked)
    }
})
```

This example is designed for 2 positions of the switch, in response you will get true or false-depending on the position of the checkbox