# create a radio bootstrap-switch dynamically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

REQUIREMENT: to create radio bootstrap switch dynamically in table.

REFERENCE: 
i am trying to implement the radio bootstrap switch as given in this link - http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/#radio-javascript

I have to create it dynamicaly. So i tried it by changing the **"Create"** example code given in the above link

The link for the js and css files are - https://github.com/BdMdesigN/bootstrap-switch/tree/master/static

PROBLEM DESCRIPTION: Able to create the bootstrap switch but **unable to handle the radio button functionality** of choosing one switch in the same group

MY CODE:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="main_table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Role Name</th>
<th>Status</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody></table>
```

in the create function i have added the following code to create radio switches for the table:

```
$('#btn-create').on('click', function () {          
        mainTable.fnAddData([
        'Role1',
        ' <input id="Role1" type="radio" name="mainTableRadio" checked >',
        '1'
        ]);
        $('#Role1').wrap('<div class="make-switch mainTableRadio"  />').parent().bootstrapSwitch();
         mainPolicyTable.fnAddData([
        'Role2',
        ' <input id="Role2" type="radio" name="mainTableRadio"  >',
        '1'
        ]);
        $('#Role2').wrap('<div class="make-switch mainTableRadio"  />').parent().bootstrapSwitch();
        $(this).remove()
    });
    $('.mainTableRadio').on('switch-change', function () {
        console.log("inside switchchange");
        $(' .make-switch.mainTableRadio').bootstrapSwitch('toggleRadioStateAllowUncheck', false);
    });
```

I am also unable to print the log in the switch-change function of the switch

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding the 'switch-change' function within the 'btn-create' click event.