# Bootstrap switch when clicked, hide the div

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, switch-statement

I've created a bootstrap switch from http://www.zamanak.ir/themes/zamanak/bootstrap-switch-3.0/

I have a div by the side of the switch so when the switch is on I want the div to appear and when its off I want the div to disappear.

How can I do it?

```
<!-- Switch -->
<link href="css/bootstrap-switch.css" rel="stylesheet">

<span class="switch-box">
            <input type="checkbox" data-on-text="<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span>" data-off-text="<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>" checked data-size="mini" id="change-color-switch" checked data-on-color="success" data-off-color="danger" class="ck-in a1">
            </span>
            <p class="conf-dy a">monday</p>

<script src="js/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>

<script>$('#change-color-switch').bootstrapSwitch('onColor','success');$('#change-color-switch').bootstrapSwitch('offColor','danger');</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
$('#change-color-switch').on('switchChange', function (e, data) {
  var state=$(this).bootstrapSwitch('state');//returns true or false
  if(state)
  {
       $("#yourdivID").show();
  }
  else
  {
       $("#yourdivID").hide();
  }
});
```

**UPDATE-**

According to the answer given **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830219/bootstrap-switch-checked-event)** `switchChange` will not be fired, it might be a bug!! So instead you need to use `switchChange.bootstrapSwitch` as below and here is the **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/m6vsdh77/)**

```
$("#change-color-switch").bootstrapSwitch();
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#change-color-switch').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (e, data) {
         var state=$(this).bootstrapSwitch('state');//returns true or false
         if(state){
             $(".conf-dy").show();
         }
         else{
             $(".conf-dy").hide();
         }
     });
});
```

Comment: Anytime buddy.. Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: I've another issue in this.

Comment: Tell me!! What is that??

Comment: Its something like this.
I want to make the div opacity to 0.3 and I want to make it inactive once the switch is toggled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75711/discussion-between-mohamed-and-guruprasad-rao).

Comment: can you come on chat room?

Comment: Thanks for the help @ Guruprasad

Comment: Can you check out my latest question about bootstrap modal?

Comment: What question?? Any link??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764041/bootstrap-modal-not-working-inside-dropdown-list?noredirect=1#comment47659967_29764041

Comment: Did you get it @Guruprasad

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the `switchChange-Event` of the bootstrap `switch`.

```
$('#change-color-switch').on('switchChange', function (e, data) {
  $(div).toggle(); 
});
```

`$(div)` being of couse the div you want to hide/show.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using jquery alone.

```js
    $('#checkbox').on('change',function(){
        $('.main')[$(this).prop('checked') ? 'fadeIn':'fadeOut']()
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
    <div class="main">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta sit iusto omnis vel et ut assumenda consequatur dolorum alias facere consectetur odio minima fugiat perspiciatis numquam ipsam optio dolorem minus!
    </div>
```