# Bootstrap Modal not working inside dropdown list

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

This is the code that I'm using. This is working fine in codepen but not in my local site.
When I open a modal outside the dropdown menu then its fine but not inside the dropdownmenu.

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
 <span class="caret"></span>
 </button>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu ul-drp" role="menu">

<li class="li-drp"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> Edit</a></li>
  <li class="li-drp"><a href="#"> Delete</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

 <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    ...
    </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using this js code for other dropdown menu to stay active

```
<script>
    $('.dropdown-menu').click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
</script>
```

If I remove this code then its working fine but I want this dropdown to stay active and open a modal.

Comment: why you are using event.stopPropagation(); try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ffx5cmkw/

Comment: bcz I've a navigation which has dropdown and inside it has for eg: Input field so it the sropdown should be active inorder to type something inside the input field if not once we click the input field to typesomething then the dropdown fades away.

Comment: have you tried using event.preventDefault();

Comment: Yes. but now I remove it. 
Anyhow I need to place the event handler bcz of other dropdown as mentioned above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok as per your inputs I read from your comments above I would assume that there will a `textbox` in `dropdown menu` and you do not want to close `dropdown` when that particular `textbox` is clicked and so the below code works.

```
$('.dropdown-menu li').click(function (event) {
     var children=$(this).children("input[type=text]");
     if(children.length!=0)
     {
         alert('found');
         event.stopPropagation();
     }
});
```

Here is the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ffx5cmkw/3/)**

Comment: Here comes my Mate :)

Comment: You're really awesome @Guru

Comment: Can I have ur email id? pls :)

Comment: come to chat please!! I can't give it here!! Come to last chat room.. :)