# bootstrapSwitch - remove eventlistener

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-switch

I would like to remove all eventlisteners from my page. For that I have an array with all the ids. I am working also with bootstrapSwitches and with them I have my problems, because after removing the eventlistener, I can add new eventlistener to all elements, but not to the bootstrapSwitch anymore.

Here is my code to remove the eventlistener:

```
for (let i = 0; i < elmIds.length; i++){
        $("#" + elmIds[i]).off();
}
```

After removing the eventlistener, setting a new one (bootstrapSwitch) doesn't work anymore:

```
 $("#" + id).on('mouseup', function(event, state) {
      doSomething({id: id, checked: event.target.checked});
 });
```

Using this code to remove eventlistener doesn´t work:

```
 $("#" + id).off('mouseup', function(event, state) {
      doSomething({id: id, checked: event.target.checked});
 });
```

It looks like, that the method `elmIds[i].off()` removes also eventlistener from the bootstrap code. What is the right way to handle eventlistener with bootstrapSwitches? Happy for some help.

---

EDIT:

To reduce the question:

How can I reattach an event to a bootstrapSwitch after removing the previous eventlistener with `$(id).off()`? Because with the statement `$(id).off()` the switch doesn't respond at all. Even if I use: `$('[name="checkbox"]').bootstrapSwitch();`

Using the code below does not remove the eventlistener:

```
 $(id).off('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
      doSomething({id: id, checked: event.target.checked});
 });
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: this is somehow related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830219/bootstrap-switch-checked-event/39450925

Comment: On that page is only info how to attach events. But I am looking for removing eventlistener in a way, that I can add another one later. The '.off()' works to remove the eventlistener, but the switch is also dead.